# How to make a curve vertex on OpenGL C++

Tags: c++, opengl, 2d

I am learning how to make a 2D object with OpenGL. I made a simple rectangle with GL_QUADS with four vertex 3f example vertex1, vertex2, vertex3, vertex4. The question is, is there anyway so I can make a curve sides from that vertex(example : from v1 to v2 is the left side of the rectangle, I just want to know how to make a curve side from v1 to v2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [Bezier curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) or something similar to generate additional vertices.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no way to draw a curve out of the box. What you could do is to draw several lines with `GL_LINE_STRIP` and to pass your vertices. Of course you have to create your own vertices.

There are several curve algorithms, but as genpfault states, the Bezier Curves are a good-looking starting point.